# Got 504 Gateway Time-out while using python multiprocessing pool in flask application

Tags: python, api, flask, timeout

My current API request takes around 40 seconds to return the response; a lot of data processing is involved. I reduced response time inside the local server by 60% using Python multiprocessing. When I tried to request from the server (application deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk), the API returned a time-out error. I tried with a small request with fewer data processing but got the same 504 response. Does Flask support a multiprocessing pool? How could I reduce the response time here? I tried multithreading, but it doesn't work.

```
# used this multiprocessing module inside the API request function
pool = multiprocessing.Pool() 
process = pool.apply_async(func=name of func,)
processes.append(process)
```

Edited:

```
@api.route(/some_api)
def trendline():
    data = some_function(request)
    return_value = {}
    return_values = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    items = [<some items>]
    for items in items:
        process = pool.apply_async(func=data_process_func(),args=(data,date,[items],),)
        processes.append(process)
    for process in processes:
        podata = process.get()
        if podata:
            return_value.update(podata)
    return_values.append(return_value)
    
    pool.close()   
    return return_values
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help you with this problem.

Comment: @SAL I've edited the initial post, and provided the example there.